# How do i invoke GSP file in framset tag

Tags: gsp, grails-2.0, frameset

I have three groovy server pages and i want display thier content within frameset tag.

```
<frameset rows="100%,*" onload="init()" onunload="terminate()">
<frame id="DisplayFrame1" name="DisplayFrame1" src="course1part1.gsp" />
<frame id="DisplayFrame2" name="DisplayFrame2" src="course1part2.gsp" />
<frame id="DisplayFrame3" name="DisplayFrame3" src="course1part3.gsp" />
<frame id="DummyFrame" name="DummyFrame" src="about:blank" />
```

When I run the application , I have this error :

> HTTP Status 404 - "/course1part1.gsp" not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the name of the GSP page directly you should use [createLink](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/createLink.html) to generate the correct URL.